# Why does HeapFree() not working as it should?

Tags: c++, memory, heapalloc

I created implementation in MVS without using CRT. I use `HeapAlloc()` and `HeapFree()` for allocating memory. My example should work without memory leak.
Here is my code:

```
LPCSTR byte2ch(BYTE* data, int size) {
    char* datas = (char*)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), NULL, size);
    LPCSTR temp = (reinterpret_cast<char const*>(data));
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        datas[i] = temp[i];
    }
    LPSTR tempo = datas;
    HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), NULL, (LPVOID)&size);
    return tempo;
}

int EntryPoint()
{
    BYTE* buffer = 0;

    HANDLE hFile;
    DWORD dwBytesRead, dwBytesWritten, dwPos;

    if (hFile = CreateFileW(L"MinerFinder.exe", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, 0, NULL))
    {
        LARGE_INTEGER size;
        GetFileSizeEx(hFile, &size);

        buffer = (BYTE*)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), NULL, size.QuadPart);
        ReadFile(hFile, buffer, size.QuadPart, &dwBytesRead, NULL);

        MessageBoxA(NULL, byte2ch(buffer, size.QuadPart), NULL, SW_SHOW);
        HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), NULL, (LPVOID)&size.QuadPart);
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "", NULL, SW_SHOW); // there I can see, that memory is leaking...
        CloseHandle(hFile);
    }

    ExitProcess(0);
}
```

Where is my mistake?

EDIT 1:

```
LPCSTR byte2ch(BYTE* data, int size) {
        char* datas = (char*)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), NULL, size);
        LPCSTR temp = (reinterpret_cast<char const*>(data));
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            datas[i] = temp[i];
        }
        LPSTR tempo = datas;
        HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), NULL, datas);
        return tempo;
    }
```

there when I `HeapFree()` program suddenly crashes. What?

Comment: `HeapFree` requires a memory block allocated with `HeapAlloc` but you are passing block size casted to pointer instead everywhere.

Comment: Also you are returning pointer to a memory block right after you are freeing it. This will not work.

Comment: Each and every one of those casts is bad. Some are unavoidable, but at least they should be replaced with `static_cast`. That said, you are supposed to extract a [mcve] from your code and provide that along with your question. As a new user, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Concerning your edit, your code still has a terrible bug. You are returning a pointer to memory that's been freed. You should take a step back and learn about object lifetimes and memory management.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [`HeapFree`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/heapapi/nf-heapapi-heapfree)

> BOOL HeapFree(
>     HANDLE                 hHeap,
>     DWORD                  dwFlags,
>     _Frees_ptr_opt_ LPVOID lpMem
>   );
>
> lpMem
>
> A pointer to the memory block to be freed. *This pointer is returned by the `HeapAlloc` or `HeapReAlloc` function*. If this pointer is NULL, the behavior is undefined.

---

In the code

```
HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), NULL, (LPVOID)&size);
HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), NULL, (LPVOID)&size.QuadPart);
```

You don't give an allocated pointer to `HeapFree`, but a pointer to the address of some unrelated (non-heap) memory.

---

The proper call would be

```
HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), NULL, datas);
```

or

```
HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), NULL, buffer);
```

Comment: HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), NULL, (LPVOID)&buffer); doesn't clearing buffer. just crash.

Comment: @korozya yes, this was my fault. It is fixed now.